# Alter hostname in Express request

Tags: node.js, apache, http, express, web

Is there a way to alter the hostname for a request on an express web server? Lets say i have web server that can be hit via the following urls:

https://servername.company.location.com/login
and
https://servername/login

is there a way to route all requests that use "https://servername/login" to "https://servername.company.location.com/login" ?  I know this can be done via apache with the RewriteRule and .htaccess file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) to forward your traffic on to the new location. You can access the current path from the request object in order to append the path:

```
// purely an example, implementation is up to you
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://servername.company.location.com/' + req.path);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work. I was wondering if there was a module or something that would mimic what apache does but oh well.